# How do I use jq to find the count of one of multiple output objects

Tags: jq

Looking to find the object count in the InUseBy element.

```
aws acm describe-certificate \
  --certificate-arn arn:### \
  | jq -r '.Certificate | [.CertificateArn, .InUseBy] | @tsv'
```

`| length` is what I want to use but I'm unsure how to limit it to just `InUseBy`

`[.CertificateArn, .InUseBy | length]` applies length to all items, how do I limit it to `InUseBy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parentheses:

```
[.CertificateArn, (.InUseBy | length)]
```

Comment: Well done on your 100K points and 8+ years of sterling service to the community.

Comment: Hehe :) Thank you! At the end I received much more than I gave. Looking forward to the next 8 years! Let's see how SO will look like then. :)